# Variable referenced before assignemnt in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I just started working with loops and somehow this is giving me an error, something with the variable pw is not right but I don't see anything wrong with it.

```
import random
import string

letters= string.printable
length= int(input( "How long do you want your password to be? "))

pw= ""

def generatePass():
  for i in range(length):
    pw = pw + random.choice(letters) #Error here
print(pw)

generatePass()
```

Any help is appreciated
Nick

Comment: You use the value of `pw` in the function, but it's not defined inside the function. You should read about scoping of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the loop, but in the communication between your function (def generatePass) and your main execution. The following works:

```
import random
import string
letters= string.printable

def generatePass(length):
    pw = ""
    for i in range(length):
        pw = pw + random.choice(letters) #Error here
    return pw


length= int(input( "How long do you want your password to be? "))

print(generatePass(length))
```

Comment: Thanks buddy,
I guess I need to try harder with functions.

Comment: You basically have to think that, inside a function, you do not share variables with the rest, unless you explicitely make them global. A function does not know what happens outside: it takes arguments, it returns stuff. And it is healthy as it is.

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is that `pw` variable is not in your function. `generatePass` does not see it. In python, functions can't access any variable outside of the function unless its a parameter or is declared global. So there are 3 ways that you can make your code working:

1. Pass `pw` as a parameter to your function:

```py
import random
import string

letters = string.printable
length = int(input("How long do you want your password to be? "))

pw = ""


def generatePass(pw):
    for i in range(length):
        pw = pw + random.choice(letters)
    return pw


print(generatePass(pw)) # here you pass the variable to a function
```

2. Create local varialbe `pw` inside the `generatePass` function:

```py
import random
import string

letters = string.printable
length = int(input("How long do you want your password to be? "))


def generatePass():
    pw = "" # here you create local variable inside a function (it is not visible outside of it)
    for i in range(length):
        pw = pw + random.choice(letters)
    return pw


print(generatePass())
```

Thanks to it you do not have to pass `pw` as a parameter to a function.

3. Make your variable `global`

```
import random
import string

letters = string.printable
length = int(input("How long do you want your password to be? "))

pw = ""


def generatePass():
    global pw # here you make pw as a global variable
    for i in range(length):
        pw = pw + random.choice(letters)
    return pw


generatePass()
print(pw)
```

Comment: Thank You Szymon, I find option nr. 2 much better than the other 2. 
The option  Nr. 3 looks weird to me ( I might have to look into that later). 
I am finding difficult passing Variables to Functions somehow. 
But thanks for showing me all 3 options.

Comment: Yes, the third option is the least used among the others and I don't recommend using it. Defining a variable as global can sometimes have unpredictable results in your code. I would suggest you to use the first one or the second one method.